# The method openDialog(String) is undefined for the type RequestContext

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog, requestcontext

I would like to open `<p:dialog>` programmatically.

I tried this code which I found in [the `DialogBean` example of PrimeFaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialogFrameworkBasic.jsf):

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("viewCars");
```

However, it caused a compile error:

> The method openDialog(String) is undefined for the type RequestContext

I looked for a way to do it in JavaScript, but it isn't clear how to do it in JavaScript. How can I open a `<p:dialog>` on press of a button?

Comment: Have you seen [`<p:dialog>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialog.jsf) showcase page? Otherwise have you checked anything at all as your question is a basic one? You'd be better off (re)starting with a basic book on JSF and/or PrimeFaces. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The PrimeFaces showcase runs currently PrimeFaces 4.0. Look closer at the version information in the site's footer. The `RequestContext#openDialog()` was introduced in PrimeFaces 4.0 and is indeed [absent in 3.5](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/3.5/org/primefaces/context/RequestContext.html). This compile error thus suggests that you're using an older version such as 3.5. In that version, you should be calling the `show()` function on the JavaScript variable referring the dialog which you can specify via `widgetVar` attribute.

E.g. purely in the view:

```
<h:form>
    <p:commandButton ... oncomplete="dialogWidget.show()" />
</h:form>
<p:dialog widgetVar="dialogWidget" ...>
    ...
</p:dialog>
```

Or via `RequestContext#execute()` if you absolutely need to:

```
<h:form>
    <p:commandButton ... action="#{bean.openDialog}" />
</h:form>
<p:dialog widgetVar="dialogWidget" ...>
    ...
</p:dialog>
```

with

```
public void openDialog() {
    // ...
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("dialogWidget.show()");
}
```

Comment: this way you can show a dialog that is contained in the current xhtml page. But if you check the PF showcase, the 'viewCars' is a different xhtml page. Is there a way to load another xhtml page with PF 3.5?

Comment: @yannicuLar: No. It's part of PF 4.0's new "dialog framework" feature. Just upgrade to PF 4.0.

Comment: no worries, I've managed to do it by including the dialog with ui:include